# Android Twilio Video Call, wake up app and bring to foreground

Tags: android, video, twilio, call, voip-android

I am trying to provide a native video calling experience with Twilio Video Call. Here is the scenario:

1. Person AAA calls person BBB.
2. Person BBB does not have the app open, in the background or foreground, app is in killed state, phone may even be locked.
3. When a call from AAA arrives, the app is opened with a video ui with an answer button. Just like in WhatsApp, Google Duo, Skype...

We have FCM in place and are receiving a push notification. Trying to open the video call answer button the moment the call arrives, without clicking the notification, just like in Whatsapp, Google Duo... (in Android phones)

We tried to have a Service running in the background with a socket open in it. The socket would listen to incoming calls and open the VideoCallActivity when an incoming call event is emitted to the socket.

This was our best bet but no success so far. How would you achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

So we had figured out this solution (when a notification arrives, bring the app to foreground) and I'm posting it even though it's been a while:

1. The FCM notification (firebase cloud messaging notification) needs to only send "data" in the notification. So no Notification object in the JSON structure of the notification, only data. This way the notification is handled by your app's FirebaseMessagingService.java class. Please read the below in detail to understand how 2 FCM notification types are handled.
   https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive
   https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages
2. In the FirebaseMessagingService.java class, launch a VideoCall activity with an Intent. Don't forget to add this service to the Manifest.xml

   ```
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, VideoCallActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
   ```
3. In the VideoCall activity, make sure you have the below code at the beginning of onCreate() :

   ```
    // These flags ensure that the activity can be launched when the screen is locked.
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    // to wake up the screen
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock((PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP), "TAG");
    wakeLock.acquire();

    // to release the screen lock
    KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock keyguardLock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock("TAG");
    keyguardLock.disableKeyguard();
   ```
4. Add the VideoCallActivity to the Manifest.xml with the appropriate intent-filter:

   ```
   <!-- Video Call -->
   <activity
       android:name=".ui.activities.video_call.VideoCallActivity"
       android:launchMode="singleTop"
       android:screenOrientation="portrait"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
       <intent-filter>
           <!-- Note: these actions are notification actions -->
           <action android:name="VIDEO_CALLING" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>
   ```

Optional:
To make the phone ring and vibrate:

```
// For Incoming Call
// 1. declare
private MediaPlayer incomingCallMediaPlayer;
// .2 in onCreate, if I'm the person that's calling, ring the phone 
incomingCallMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.incoming);
incomingCallMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
incomingCallMediaPlayer.start();
// 3. when I pick up, stop the player
incomingCallMediaPlayer.stop();

// I play R.raw.incoming if I'm being called.
// I play R.raw.outgoing when I'm calling.
// I understand if I'm the one calling from the number of participants in the "room" (this is a video call terminology) and bypassing in a variable through the intent

// For Outgoing Call
// 1. declare
private MediaPlayer callingMediaPlayer;

// 2. in onCreate, if I'm being called, ring the phone
callingMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.outgoing);
callingMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
callingMediaPlayer.start();

// 3. when another "participant" (this is a video call terminology) joins the "room" I stop playing the sound
callingMediaPlayer.stop();

// to Vibrate, add the code with the media players and stop vibrate with media players
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950338/how-to-make-an-android-device-vibrate
```

Comment: Is using FCM push notification effective in real time? or is there any better option to do so, some time push notification wont reach the client immediately it may delay right?

Comment: @Praneeth Not that I know of but if anyone else has a better option than fcm push notification please share. Praneeth we tried having a socket open in the background for incoming video calls but didn't quite work. It complicated the process. However, during many internal tests and in the alpha group we didn't see any issues with delay.

Comment: I have implemented twilio video calling in my app and the push is working fine in foreground but when it is in back ground I'm unable to open my activity, even I'm sending data message it is displayed in the notification tray

Comment: can you please explain how you are bringing the app to forground when app is closed or locked

Comment: When the notification arrives, the data in the notification is handled by FireBaseMessagingService.java class as described in step 2 and starts an intent to open VideoCallActivity class. The code in step 3. allows the app to unlock the come to the foreground. I am guessing you also have the FirebaseMessagingService in the Manifest. If you've done all these it should work. If you'd like I can take a look at your code.

Comment: thank you for your time, Yes I have class which extends FireBaseMessagingService and Implements onMessageRecived call back method  I need to send data message alone I think.

Comment: When my app is in background when I send a push notification, the push notification is shown in notification tray as normal push notification, my app is not coming to for ground.

Comment: Okay, since it is working when the app is in the foreground but not in the background, it makes me think the issue is with the notification. This tricked me for a while to understand the difference between 2 notifications. The following link will help you on Data and Notification notifications: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages

Comment: How are you handling when the app enter into Doze mode in android

Comment: To be honest, I didn't. You just brought it to my attention and thank you for that.

Comment: Ok I think I will figure it out, once I got any solution I will update here, can we able to make phone vibrate or ring a tone when we handle notification?

Comment: I added the code to ring and vibrate in my original answer. Let me know if clear or any problems you encounter.

Comment: @Praneeth hi - did you ever figure this out? :)

Comment: @ousanmaz for the second point, on which event, the code will be called.. onMessageReceived works only when the app is in foreground IMO

Comment: hi, i also looking for this. any one have the solution?  need some one to save my day lol